# Why there is spaces at the right of my Page at Responsiveness

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a React Project in which i have made a home page that shows `Property` `Award` `feature` section and show great on web pages. But when i adjust it for mobile version it start showing some empty spaces at the right.
Firstly i though this is due to my Navbar Component but i tried to remove the `Navbar` which result still in the same problem. I want to eliminate the empty spaces which is coming at the right side of my website at the time of mobile responsiveness.

[image: This is Landing Page]

Now when i check for mobile then it shows

[image]

You can check for the right spaces.

`Hero.jsx`

```
import "./hero.css";
import price from "./Assets/negotiation.png";
import homeap from "./Assets/ab.png";
import paper from "./Assets/paperwork.png";
import { Typewriter, Cursor } from "react-simple-typewriter";
import girldp1 from "./Assets/girl_dp1.jpg";
import girldp2 from "./Assets/gir_dp2.jpg";
import girldp3 from "./Assets/gir_dp3.jpg";
import mandp1 from "./Assets/man_dp1.jpg";
import mandp2 from "./Assets/man_dp2.jpg";
import mandp3 from "./Assets/man_dp3.jpg";
import Featured from "./featured/Featured";
import Team from "./Team/Team";
import Awards from "./Awards/Awards";
export function HeroText() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="main">
        <div className="Landing">
          <div className="image-overlay"></div>
          <h1 className="overlay-text" style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
            <span style={{ color: "black" }}>
              <Typewriter
                words={["Exceptional Service, Extraordinary Results."]}
                loop={5}
                typeSpeed={100}
                deleteSpeed={90}
                delaySpeed={1000}
              />
            </span>

            <span>
              <Cursor />
            </span>
          </h1>
        </div>

        <div>
          <Featured />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Awards/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Team />
        </div>

        <div id="abc">
          <div className="WeHand">
            <div className="heading1">
              <h1>We Handle Everything</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="WeHandtxt">
              <div className="interior">
                <img src={homeap} alt="logo" />
                <h3>Home Appraisal</h3>
                <p>
                  We understand the significance of accurate home valuations.
                  Our team of experienced and certified appraisers meticulously
                  assesses various factors that influence the value of your
                  property. From the location and size of your home to its
                  condition and recent market trends, we leave no stone
                  unturned.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="interior">
                <img src={price} alt="logo" />
                <h3>Price Negotation</h3>
                <p>
                  {" "}
                  We believe in advocating for our clients and ensuring they get
                  the most out of their real estate investments. Our skilled
                  negotiators have extensive experience in the industry, and we
                  are committed to securing the most favorable terms for you. We
                  leverage our in-depth market knowledge and strategic approach
                  to engage in price negotiations that align with your goals.{" "}
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="interior">
                <img src={paper} alt="logo" />
                <h3>Paperwork Handling </h3>
                <p>
                  {" "}
                  We understand the importance of handling paperwork accurately
                  and efficiently. Our experienced team takes care of drafting,
                  reviewing, and submitting all necessary documents, ensuring
                  compliance with regulations and minimizing risks. Trust us to
                  handle your real estate paperwork seamlessly, guiding you
                  through the process for a smooth and successful transaction.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="get-started">
            <h1>Get Started</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="get-started1">
            <p>
              Don't wait to invest in your Dream Property! <br /> Explore Our
              Website or Contact our experts agent for your real estate needs.{" "}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="buttons">
            <button id="button1">Explore Properties</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="review" id="Review">
          <h1>
            Customer's <span>Review</span>
          </h1>
          <div className="ReviewCont">
            <div className="review_card">
              <div className="card_top">
                <div className="profile_image">
                  <img src={mandp3} alt="/" />
                </div>
                <div className="profileNameArea">
                  <div className="name">
                    <strong>Sparsh</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div className="like">
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="reviewComment">
                ""WXHomes is an incredible real estate website. It offers an
                intuitive user interface, making property searches and
                navigation a breeze. The detailed property information and
                high-quality images provide a clear understanding of each
                listing. It's a reliable and efficient platform for finding your
                dream home."
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="review_card">
              <div className="card_top">
                <div className="profile_image">
                  <img src={girldp1} alt="/" />
                </div>
                <div className="profileNameArea">
                  <div className="name">
                    <strong>Kanika</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div className="like">
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="reviewComment">
                "I highly recommend WXHomes for anyone looking to buy or sell
                real estate. The website offers a wide range of listings, and
                the search filters help narrow down options based on specific
                preferences. The responsive customer support team is always
                ready to assist and provide valuable guidance throughout the
                process."{" "}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="review_card">
              <div className="card_top">
                <div className="profile_image">
                  <img src={mandp1} alt="/" />
                </div>
                <div className="profileNameArea">
                  <div className="name">
                    <strong>Mohit</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div className="like">
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              WXHomes is my go-to website for finding rental properties. The
              platform is user-friendly, and the rental listings are regularly
              updated. The ability to schedule virtual tours and the
              comprehensive property descriptions save time and make the rental
              search hassle-free. If you're looking for a rental, give WXHomes a
              try{" "}
            </div>

            <div className="review_card">
              <div className="card_top">
                <div className="profile_image">
                  <img src={girldp3} alt="/" />
                </div>
                <div className="profileNameArea">
                  <div className="name">
                    <strong>Neha</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div className="like">
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              I highly recommend WXHomes for real estate needs. Its wide range
              of listings and search filters help narrow down options based on
              preferences. The responsive customer support team offers valuable
              guidance throughout the process."{" "}
            </div>

            <div className="review_card">
              <div className="card_top">
                <div className="profile_image">
                  <img src={mandp2} alt="/"/>
                </div>
                <div className="profileNameArea">
                  <div className="name">
                    <strong>Piyush</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div className="like">
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              "WXHomes is my go-to website for rental properties. regularly
              updated listings make the rental search hassle-free. Virtual tours
              and comprehensive property descriptions save time. Give WXHomes a
              try for an easy rental search."
            </div>

            <div className="review_card">
              <div className="card_top">
                <div className="profile_image">
                  <img src={girldp2} alt="/"/>
                </div>
                <div className="profileNameArea">
                  <div className="name">
                    <strong>Sakshi</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div className="like">
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star" />
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              WXHomes made selling my property a great experience. The seamless
              listing process and marketing tools helped attract potential
              buyers quickly. Thanks to WXHomes, I sold my property efficiently
              and with peace of mind."
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

`Hero.css`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&display=swap');



.aboutHead {

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.aboutHead h1 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 70px;
  font-size: 5.5vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  animation: slideIn 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}


@keyframes bounce {

  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  40%,
  43% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0) scaleY(1.1);
  }

  70% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0) scaleY(1.05);
  }

  80% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scaleY(0.95);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0) scaleY(1.02);
  }
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}




.aboutGrid {
  display: grid;
  width: 97.5vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -13px;


  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

  column-gap: 2vw;

}


@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInLeft {
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
}

.aboutGridText {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  font-size: 20px;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 70vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  align-content: center;
  color: #2F1D37;
  animation: moverSombraRosa 6s infinite;
}


/* FindStyle.css */

.containerFindDreams {
  width: 190vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  margin-top: 70px;
  column-gap: 5vw;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.item {
  font-size: 2vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item h1 {
  margin: 0 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#findhead {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 137);
  animation: bounce 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {

  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  40%,
  43% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0) scaleY(1.1);
  }

  70% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0) scaleY(1.05);
  }

  80% {
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scaleY(0.95);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0) scaleY(1.02);
  }
}

.bounce {
  animation-name: bounce;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.itemHead {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  margin: auto;
}


@keyframes jackInTheBox {
  from {
    opacity: 50;
    transform: scale(0.5) rotate(30deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }

  70% {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.jackInTheBox {
  animation-name: jackInTheBox;
}

#tophead {
  margin: 0%;
}


#image {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
}


#button2 {
  color: #24a0ed;

  border-radius: 27px;
  border-color: #24a0ed;
}


#button1 {
  color: #24a0ed;

  border-radius: 27px;
  border-color: #24a0ed;
}

#button3 {
  color: #24a0ed;

  border-radius: 27px;
  border-color: #24a0ed;
}

#button4 {
  color: #24a0ed;

  border-color: #24a0ed;

  border-radius: 27px;
  border-color: #24a0ed;
}



#button {
  color: #24a0ed;

  border-radius: 27px;
  border-color: #24a0ed;

}

#tagline {

  color: rgb(139, 137, 135);
  margin: 0%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border;

}

.Awesome3 {
  width: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 95vh;
  margin-bottom: 17vh;
  margin-top: 10vh;
}

.heading {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.heading p {

  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  color: #423A4C;
}


.containerAwesome {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.ContA {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.ContA:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ServiceContDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.ServiceHead {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ServiceTxt {
  color: #555;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
}

#button:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(255, 194, 141);
  color: rgb(78, 23, 23);
}



/* We Handle */

.WeHand {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
}

.WeHandtxt {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.interior {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#abc h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  animation: bounce 3s infinite;
}

.heading1 p {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.interior {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.interior img {
  width: 100px;
  /* Adjust the width as desired */
  height: auto;
}

/* getting Started */
.get-started {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.get-started h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #333;
}

.get-started1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.get-started1 p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #666;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#button1 {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #24a0ed;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#button1:hover {
  background-color: #187bcd;
}

/* review */
.review {
  margin: 15vh 20px 0px 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #423A4C;
  ;
}

h1 span {

  color: #423A4C;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(192, 210, 219, 0.5);

}

.interior h3 {
  color: #423A4C;
}

.interior p {
  color: #423A4C;
}


.text-with-glow {
  animation: shine 1.5s infinite;
}

.ReviewCont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.review_card {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card_top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.profile_image img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.profileNameArea {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.like {
  color: #ff9800;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.reviewComment {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


.Landing {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* Set the aspect ratio of the image, e.g., 16:9 */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3%;
  left: 15%;
  font-size: 3vw;

}


.image-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("./Assets/home.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}
```

In this i have remove the `<Navbar/>` but still facing the issue.
You can check the website from here https://real-estwx.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

After checking your code seems like the problem is with:

`box-sizing: border`

It should be:
`border-box`.

Comment: i did this but what is happening it start focusing on the main thing but when i swipe right it start displaying same blank spaces thing again.